# swift osx NSSearchField reset programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3, nssearchfield

I'm quite new to swift,
I'm trying to reset a NSSearchField programmatically, but I didn't find a proper way to do this!
At the moment I'm doing in this way

```
import Cocoa

extension NSSearchField {
    func reset() {
        self.stringValue = ""
        let cell = self.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell
        let cancelButton = cell?.cancelButtonCell
        cancelButton?.performClick(self)
    }

}
```

EDIT:
My problem is that in  NSSearchFieldDelegate the function controlTextDidChange is not called.

how to call to do that?
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you do `self.stringValue = ""`?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do.  Why do you even need to write an tension for NSSearchField?  let cancelButton = cell?.cancelButtonCell ???

Comment: @adev this will empty the textView in the searchField

Comment: @ElTomato I need to empy/clear the NSSearchField every time I show hide my view.
At the moment I found this workaround, but this is not triggering any event, and I've to update manually the search result.

Comment: Well you said `self.stringValue = ""` will empty. And your last comment says that is what you wanted to do too. Then what is the problem here? Why don't you just use that alone? Why do you even need to do `performClick` on `cancelButtonCell`?

Comment: Which event do you want to trigger?

Comment: edited the question :
My problem is that in NSSearchFieldDelegate the function controlTextDidChange is not called.

Comment: Delegate messages aren't sent for programmatic changes: the assumption is that your code doesn't need a callback for something it's doing itself.

Answer (score 0):

**set your delegate, otherwise controlTextDidChange will not be called**:

Your extension is not the problem.

here is an example,

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSearchFieldDelegate {

// Search Field
@IBOutlet weak var mySearchField: NSSearchField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Don't forget to set delegate
    self.mySearchField.delegate = self

}

// Driver program
@IBAction func onPress(_ sender: Any) {
    // clear search field
    self.mySearchField.reset()
}

// View output
override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    print("--");
}
}

extension NSSearchField {

func reset() {
    self.stringValue = ""
    //let cell = self.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell
    //let cancelButton = cell?.cancelButtonCell
    //cancelButton?.performClick(self)
}
}
```